# where to put test gems in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rubygems, development-environment

I've seen different sources where the test gems are placed in other groups of the gemfile. For example in one tut the `factory_girl_rails` is in `group :development, :test` and in another it's in `group :test`.

Is there an easy way to decide where to put the following gems?

```
factory_girl_rails
launchy
jasmine
guard-rspec
capybara
shoulda
```

Comment: I would put anything you don't actively use in development in the `test` group. Those gems seem to be used only for running tests. It depends on how you're using them but I don't think you need any of those in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what they usually say on their github repo page, but usually put the test ones only in the `:test` group (i.e. `jasmine`, `guard-rspec`, `capybara`, `shoulda`) and if you ever need them in dev (Creating a factory in dev can sometimes be cool), then put it in both.

Truth be told, I don't know launchy...

Comment: So in the beginning only the `rspec-rails` (I forgot to mention in the question) should be in the dev+test group? The repos usually don't specify the group.

Comment: Yep, since they specify it on their page: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails. Otherwise I'd put them in one or the other (`:development` or `:test`) by default